# Struggling with data input for R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

This is my first ever post so do let me know if there's anything not right or how I can improve, I am a complete novice to all this. For example, I didn't know how to make a proper table for my data so it is in bullet points.

So I currently have a data output from running a qPCR. I have the relative expression of my gene of interest in my treatments alongside the Standard Error, 95% Confidence intervals and P(H1) probability result is due to chance.

```
Gene      Relative Expression   Standard Error    95% CI    P(H1)
Reference  1.00
Target Gene  0.818               0.548-1.304      0.441-1.370  0.399
```

I want to create a bar chart showing my relative expression with standard error bars. I've had problems in the past with R and just wondered if it is possible to save "0.818       0.548-1.304" as a .txt file and have R plot a bar chart in this way, with these standard error bars?

From most research R seems to like calculating its own standard error, so I'm wondering if there is a way I can personalise it to my own, already calculated, standard error?

Comment: For the table formatting, one easy way to do it is to format it as a code block (verbatim). You can do it either by clicking on the `{}` icon in the editor or by prefixing each code line with 3 spaces

Comment: Thank you very much Pierre, this will be very useful for what I imagine will be very many more cries for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `geom_errorbar()` to plot your own confidence intervals.

For example (bioinformatics is not my field, I'm making stuff up, sorry :D):

```
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- data.frame(gene = c("A", "B", "C"),
                     RE = c(0.818, 0.627, 0.722),
                     CI_low = c(0.548, 0.401, 0.564),
                     CI_high = c(1.304, 1.11, 1.215))

mydata

  gene    RE CI_low CI_high
1    A 0.818  0.548   1.304
2    B 0.627  0.401   1.110
3    C 0.722  0.564   1.215


ggplot(mydata) +
    geom_col(aes(x = gene, y = RE)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(x = gene, ymin = CI_low, ymax = CI_high))
```

[image: dynamite plot]

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! I must confess I am not much of a bioinformatician either, I'm a masters student but up until now all my data presentation has been done in excel and SPSS. I've been struggling with R so much over the past few weeks so this means a great deal to me! :D I don't suppose you could link me anything that helped you become proficient with R? I shall make sure to thank you in my thesis!

Comment: Glad to help! Sure thing, if you want to become a proficient, happy R user you can start here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/